# Receiving parameters by URL loads all the content

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a project that shows orders between dates with two dates

Route:

```
Route::get('/order/manage/all/{date1?}{date2?}', [\App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::class, 'all'])->name('order.manage.all');
```

View:

```
    <form method="GET" action="{{route('order.manage.all')}}" id="buscador">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="date1" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Fecha1</label>

                <input type="date" class="mb-2"name="date1"/>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="date2" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Fecha2</label>
                <input type="date" class="mb-2" name="date2"/>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group col">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Filtrar"/>
            </div>   
        </div>

    </form>

    @foreach($orders as $order)
    <div class="card mb-5 line">
        <h3 class="text-center">{{"Fecha de pedido: ".$order->date_order." | "."Referencia: ".$order->reference}} </h3>
        <h3 class="text-center">{{$order->address->name." ".$order->address->surname1." ".$order->address->surname2}}</h3>
        <h3 class="text-center">{{$order->address->address." (".$order->address->region.", ".$order->address->city.")"}}</h3>

        <p class="text-center">{{\OrderItemHelper::countOrderItems($order->id)}} productos</p>
    </div>

    @endforeach
```

Controller:

```
public function all($date1 = null, $date2 = null) {
        var_dump($date1);
        var_dump($date2);
        if (!empty($date1) && !empty($date2)) {
            $orders = Order::whereBetween('date_order', [$date1, $date2])->get();
        } else {
            $orders = Order::orderBy('date_order', 'desc')->get();
        }
        return view('order.all', [
            'orders' => $orders
        ]);
    }
```

The problem I have is that when I receive these parameters by the URL (when doing the var_dump of $date1 it loads me all the content of the URL. And the $date2 returns null)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually using the route parameters here. You are using the request inputs from the query string. Route parameters are from the URI (which does not include the query string).

With what you are doing you would drop the parameters from the route definition and get the dates from the request.

```
Route::get('/order/manage/all', [\App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::class, 'all'])->name('order.manage.all');

public function all(Request $request)
{
    $date1 = $request->input('date1');
    $date2 = $request->input('date2');


    ...
}
```

Though, it looks like you may have a misconfigured server to go along with this as the query string might be being passed without the '?' and its ending up as a part of the path [based on your data dump].